# select multiple files in file upload in php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, frontend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select multiple files for upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525972/how-to-select-multiple-files-for-upload)

i know that php doesn't allow you to select multiple files to upload in one box.

is there a work around or do you have to learn another language for it?