# How to select multiple files for upload?

Tags: php, javascript, html, file-upload, upload

How to select multiple files for upload :
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This depends on the browser. Newer versions of firefox and chrome support this because they started to implement HTML5 specification. This is the syntax:

```
<input type="file" multiple=""/>
```

Firefox >= 3.6, Chrome >= 2, Safari  >= 4 support multiple file input.

For older browsers the only good solutions are flash or javascript plugins. 
Here is a good resource for jquery uploaders ( some support multiple files ): http://creativefan.com/10-ajax-jquery-file-uploaders/

Comment: you meant flash or java plugins probably?. AFAIK javascript won't help you to select multiple files with 1 file element.

Comment: Stann: there are javascript plugins that just create a new file element whenever the previous one has a value.

Answer (score 7):

In HTML5 you can set the [`multiple` attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.multiple) on `<input type="file">`. This works in browsers supporting HTML5.

```
<input type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple" />
```

In HTML4 your best bet is Flash or Java Applet. There are 3rd party libs available like [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/), [SWFupload](http://swfupload.org/), [JUpload](http://jupload.sourceforge.net/) and [JumpLoader](http://jumploader.com/).

Comment: +1 for JumpLoader...I've been looking all over for something just like it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would definately at this point go with new HTML5 "multiple" attribute:

```
<input type="file" name="upload[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

The only viable alternative is FLASH plugins like swfupload.

However  - there are multiple prublems with using FLASH for uploads, the main one foor me would be cookie bug:

FLASH plugins don't send cookies correctly. Each browser has it's own cookie storage.FLASH always sends cookies from IE even if you use Google Chrome for example. - result is that you loose cookies and sessions.  there is a workaround - but it requires you to send session ID as GET or POST parameters which in turn makes your site vulnerable for session fixation.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use javascript plugins such as: http://code.google.com/p/noswfupload/

Answer (score 1):

Use the file input form element more than once, give it a different name and you have multiple upload fields on one page. No need to learn anything else.

Answer (score 1):

1. PHP is the **back-end**, PHP is not the thing which restricts you to use only "one" upload a time
2. **HTML/JavaScript** are the front/mid-end which cause the restrictions. (So add HTML to your questions tags)
3. If you use Flash (AS = **ActionScript**) you can still have *PHP as back-end*, as processor which handles the uploaded files.

Answer (score -1):

There is no html/javascript workaround. You would have to look to flash or java to be able to do this.

Answer (score -1):

As others have said, you have to use Flash to get multiple uploads.  An alternative to uploadify is [SWFUpload](http://swfupload.org/).

Answer (score -1):

Flash is the only option except HTML5.

Comment: and also java applets. but flash is better since most folks have it already installed.